# Remove all default logging from Minimal Web API C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, minimal-apis

Is it possible to remove all logging from the minimal web api? I searched for it and my code currently looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(b => {
    b.ClearProviders();
});
```

This almost works for everything besides the startup message seen below:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: PATH REDACTED
```

Is it possible to remove this startup message as well?

Comment: You could use `builder.Logging.ClearProviders();` which will remove all loggin with project.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I tried that, but still shows the startup message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check appsettings.json files (including environment specific ones) and set values there to `None`. For example for default ones:

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

Also check out the [logging docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#configure-logging) (and [ASP.NET Core specific ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0), though they should be quite similar).

Answer (score 2):

The way to clear logger providers is via:

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
```

Disabling logging via configuration is also a valid alternative.